# How to pass between guis in matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am doing a group project and we are supposed to be using GUIS to create a presentation. In the presentation there is data that is loaded in using an edit text box and our code then goes through calculations and if statements and is supposed to pass certain values to a different GUI.  Our instructors do not know how to do it because we have asked them on several occasions and they cannot figure it out.  We have tried varargin method and the getappdata method and neither one is working. Does anyone have suggestions? PLEEAASE!!

Comment: Have you tried storing the values in the appdata in the root? Ex. `setappdata(0,'name',value);` => `getappdata(0,'name');`

Comment: what does in the root mean?

Comment: The use of appdata can be with a figure handle where in this case the root is what I believe to be the MATLAB application which is where you are running all of these scripts and function files from. So you can store the data there since everything you run will have knowledge of the root ( `0` ) instead of needing the specific figure handle reference.

Answer (score 0):

I would write some "Controller" program that will know open the figures for you and know how to forward the data. Basically it would be a simplified [mvc-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). It could also assure the figures are opened in correct order.